# Adding UIImageView to custom UITableViewCell

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, uitableview, uiimageview

I can't seem to add this imageview to my custom uitableviewcell class and i can't figure it out. Here is my code:

```
- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code
        [self layoutCell];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)layoutCell
{
    self.videoImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(5, 5, 310, 120)];
    [self.videoImageView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"myImage.jpg"]];
    [self.contentView addSubview:self.imageView];
}
```

In the debugger, i noticed that once i add the imageview as a subview of the contentview, the frame gets reassigned to (0,0,0,0) if that helps. I really have no idea whats going on. If anyone has any suggestions that'd be awesome. I've also tried adding the imageview directly to the cell's view itself, to no avail. (and im pretty sure thats wrong anyway).

Tahnks!

Comment: Try implementing layoutSubviews method in tablecell class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Implement `layoutSubviews` method and check if that makes any difference. It should fix this.

```
- (void)layoutSubviews
{
  videoImageView.frame = CGRectMake(5, 5, 310, 120);
}
```

**Update:**

Try changing the `layoutCell` method from `init` method. Instead call it as `[cell layoutCell]` in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method of tableview. This will make sure that even if the dequeureuse is called while reloading, it will properly set the UIImage and frame. You can just add `self.videoImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(5, 5, 310, 120)] ;` in your `init` method.

```
- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code
        self.videoImageView = [[[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(5, 5, 310, 120)] autorelease]; //no need of autorelease if ARC is used
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)layoutCell
{
    self.videoImageView.frame = CGRectMake(5, 5, 310, 120);
    [self.videoImageView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"myImage.jpg"]];
    [self.contentView addSubview:self.videoImageView];
}
```

In `cellForRowAtIndexPath`,

```
//create cell
[cell layoutCell];

return cell;
```

Answer (score 2):

You should not set your image in `init` method of cell. You need to keep it separate.

Answer (score 0):

You alloc the self.videoImageView and then add a self.imageView to the contentView (seems as a mis typing). Also you can do as others suggested that move your UI init method to somewhere else than initWithStyle. That will help.